# How to compute xslant and yslant

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, slanted

There must be an easy way to compute the required values of `xslant` and `yslant` to obtain the text in the "correct plane". Below I have guessed at then, but that is a very tedious process. The desired results should be that the following lines should not have any magic numbers:

```
\tikzset{yz slant style/.style={red,    yslant=-0.5,  xslant=-0.1}}
\tikzset{xy slant style/.style={blue,   yslant=-0.25, xslant=1   }}
\tikzset{xz slant style/.style={orange, yslant=1,     xslant=0.05}}
```

and instead should be based on the values of `\xc`,`\xs`,`\yc`, and `\ys` (or `\elevation` and `\anglerot`).  My guessed value produce something which I think are  *close*:

[image]

### Notes:

- I realize that this is more of a math question, but without fully understanding how `tikz`/`pgf` works I don't know how to compute them.
- The preamble code is from [3D Arrow Tips for TikZ/pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51340/3d-arrow-tips-for-tikz-pgfplots).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51388/4301
\newcommand*\elevation{14}
\newcommand*\anglerot{-50}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xc{cos(\anglerot)}  
\pgfmathsetmacro\xs{sin(\anglerot)}   
\pgfmathsetmacro\yc{cos(\elevation)} 
\pgfmathsetmacro\ys{sin(\elevation)} 
\newcommand*\axexthreed{\xs*1cm,-\xc*1cm} 
\newcommand*\axeythreed{\yc*1cm,-\ys*1cm}
\newcommand*\axezthreed{0cm,1cm} 

\newcommand*{\CoordX}{3}%
\newcommand*{\CoordY}{4}%
\newcommand*{\CoordZ}{5}%

%% How do I compute these:
\tikzset{yz slant style/.style={red, yslant=-0.5, xslant=-0.1}}
\tikzset{xy slant style/.style={blue, yslant=-0.25, xslant=1}}
\tikzset{xz slant style/.style={orange, yslant=1, xslant=0.05}}



\begin{tikzpicture}[x = {(\axexthreed)},
                    y = {(\axeythreed)},
                    z = {(\axezthreed)},
                    ]

    \draw[black, ultra thick,-latex] (-1,0,0) -- (\CoordX,0,0) node[black,left=6pt]  {$x$}; 
    \draw[black, ultra thick,-latex] (0,-1,0) -- (0,\CoordY,0) node[black,right=6pt] {$y$}; 
    \draw[black, ultra thick,-latex] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,\CoordZ) node[black,above=6pt] {$z$};       

    \foreach \x in {1,...,\CoordX} {
        \draw [thin, draw=gray] (\x,\CoordY,0) -- (\x,0,0)
            node [left, yz slant style] at ($(\x,0,0)+(-0.2,0,0)$) {\x};
    }
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\CoordY} {
        \draw [thin, draw=gray] (\CoordX,\x,0) -- (0,\x,0)
            node [right, xy slant style] at ($(0,\x,0)+(-0.4,-0.3,0)$) {\x};
    }
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\CoordZ} {
        \draw [thin, draw=gray] (\CoordX,0,\x) -- (0,0,\x)
            node [right, xz slant style] at ($(0,0,\x)+(0,-0.0,-0.2)$) {\x};
    }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I avoid yslant.  Rotate together with xslant are enough.  The rotate angle should be obvious, and the xslant is either the cos or sin.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Hadn't thought of that. You want to post a complete answer?

Comment: Related Question: [Text projection onto plane in 3D pgf plots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212699/text-projection-onto-plane-in-3d-pgf-plots).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Okay, yslant to spin vertical letters, rotate and xslant to lay letters flat, xscale and yscale for forehortening.

```
\tikzset{yz slant style/.style={red, yslant=-tan(\elevation), xscale=cos(\elevation)}}
\tikzset{xy slant style/.style={blue, xslant=-tan(\elevation+\anglerot), rotate=-\elevation, yscale=cos(\anglerot)}}
\tikzset{xz slant style/.style={orange, yslant=-cot(\anglerot), xscale=sin(-\anglerot)}}
```

[image: axes]