# 2D Bar Chart in 3D Space

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I have a graph in 3D space and I'd like to add a histogram along the vertical axis. The bars are supposed to be spaced equally along the vertical axis. I am, however, unable to get the positions of the bars correctly. Here is a MWE of what I have tried so far.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  view={35}{15},
  height=3in, width=3in,
  xmin=0, xmax=1,
  ymin=0, ymax=1,
  zmin=0, zmax=1,
  3d box=complete,
  xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, zlabel=$z$]
\addplot3 [xbar,bar width=2pt] coordinates{
(0.51,0,0.00) (1.00,0,0.05) (0.82,0,0.10) (0.45,0,0.15) (0.20,0,0.20) (0.30,0,0.25) (0.04,0,0.30) (0.06,0,0.35) (0.19,0,0.40) (0.17,0,0.45) (0.12,0,0.50) (0.09,0,0.55) (0.13,0,0.60) (0.30,0,0.65) (0.11,0,0.70) (0.28,0,0.75) (0.06,0,0.80) (0.21,0,0.85) (0.46,0,0.90) (0.24,0,0.95) (0.01,0,1.00)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

My understanding is that the last element of each coordinate point should determine the position of the bar along the Z-axis, while the first element specifies the height. I meant to have the bars equally spaced, though, as seen from the below picture, the output is not produced as such.

[image]

Also, my second question is that how I can get the bars rotated around the Z-axis such that they lie flatly on the Y-Z plane rather than hanging up in the space like in the picture above.

Comment: You need to add a slant to those lines, something like `yslant=0.4` seems to produce ok results.  Also [How to compute xslant and yslant](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170244/how-to-compute-xslant-and-yslant) may help.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterGrill. Sounds like `yslant` does the rotation trick! I am still wondering why the bar positions are messed up.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the pgfplots manual:

> 4.6.11     About 3D Const Plots and 3D Bar Plots
>
> There are currently no equivalents of `const plot` and its variants or the bar plot types
>   like `ybar` for three dimensional axes, sorry.

Your request is actually a feature request. I will write it to the todo list of pgfplots.

Comment: That's sad! There should still exist a hack for it though, eh?

Comment: The only one that I know of is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52987/3-dimensional-histogram-in-pgfplots