# Text projection onto plane in 3D pgf plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'd like to have text that appears as though it's written "on" one of the walls of a 3D tikz plot.  MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,3d}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    view={60}{30},
    %axis equal,
    clip=false,
    xmin=0,xmax=1,
    ymin=0,ymax=1,
    zmin=0,zmax=1,
    ]

    %\addplot3 (1,1,1);

    \path (axis cs:0,0,0) -- (axis cs:0,1,0) node[midway,above, sloped,xslant=0.2] {Text};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE1]

The thing that I'm not happy with in this case is that I needed to set `xslant` manually.  I could calculate it based on geometry, but pgfplots angles seem to not always be as you would expect. Example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,3d}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    view={45}{90},
    %axis equal,
    clip=false,
    xmin=0,xmax=1,
    ymin=0,ymax=1,
    zmin=0,zmax=1,
    ]

    %\addplot3 (1,1,1);

    \path (axis cs:0,0,0) -- (axis cs:0,1,0) node[midway,above, sloped,xslant=0.2] {Text};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE2]

[this is exactly he same as the previous example except that I've changed the view].  This gives a view of the plot from directly above, showing that the x and y axes are not perpendicular.  I think that this can be changed with `axis equal` or `axis equal image`, but I'd rather not use those as they have side-effects.

I assume that pgfplots has internally calculated how the x, y, and z direction vectors are mapped to the 2-D page... is there a way that I can extract this information? If I had that available, then it would be easy to find the appropriate slope using trig.  This would work without `axis equal` or `axis equal image`

Comment: Related Question: [How to compute xslant and yslant](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170244/how-to-compute-xslant-and-yslant).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wasn't sure whether you wanted flat or vertical letters, so I did both.  Note the use of [scale mode=scale uniformly].  Also note that yscale is the denominator of xslant, and xscale is the denominator of yslant.

[image: text in 3d]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,3d}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\h{80}% horizontaql viewing angle
\def\v{10}% vertical viewing angle
\begin{axis}[
    scale mode=scale uniformly,
    view={\h}{\v},
    clip=false,
    xmin=0,xmax=1,
    ymin=0,ymax=1,
    zmin=0,zmax=1,
   ]
  \pgfmathparse{atan(tan(\h)*sin(\v))}
  \let\a=\pgfmathresult
  \pgfmathparse{atan(tan(90-\h)*sin(\v))}
  \let\b=\pgfmathresult  

    \path (axis cs:0,0,0) -- (axis cs:0,1,0) node[color=blue,midway,above,sloped,
    xslant=tan(\a+\b+90),yscale=sin(\a+\b)] {Text};

    \path (axis cs:0,0,0) -- (axis cs:0,1,0) node[color=red,midway,above,
    yslant=tan(\b),xscale=cos(\b)] {Text};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: do the math]

Comment: I like this! Is there a reason that you used option "sloped" for the blue text and just explicitly set xslant for the red text?

Comment: Flat text is best done using rotate (sloped) and xslant.  Vertical text is best done using yslant.

Comment: Cool. I'm accepting this because I think you've got all the ingredients I need, but I think that there is a mistake in the blue text alignment. It looks right with the combination of angles you have, but it doesn't seem to adjust properly for other values.

Comment: I went back and did the math.  It might be possible to simplify the calculations, but right now my brain hurts.

Comment: Haha, I did the math too. I think the way that seems most intuitive to me is to use the transformation matrix instead of setting slants and scales individually. This was also the only way that made sense to me when I tried to project text on the the x-y plane (which is a more complicated transformation)... I'll post this as another answer

Answer (score 3):

You should switch to `PST-solides3d`, which can produce much satisfying projection of texts and also figures. See the following examples from its [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-solides3d/doc/pst-solides3d-doc.pdf):
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Building on John's solution, here is a MWE which uses option `cm` to explicitly set the transformation matrix for each node:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\newcommand{\viewa}{30}
\newcommand{\viewb}{30}

\begin{axis}[scale mode=scale uniformly,% needed for text
    view={\viewa}{\viewb},
    clip=false,
    xmin=0,xmax=1,
    ymin=0,ymax=1,
    zmin=0,zmax=1,
    ]           

    \node[color=red,
        cm={sin(\viewa),cos(\viewa)*sin(\viewb),
        0,cos(\viewb),
        (0,0)}
            ]   
     at (axis cs:0,0.5,0.5) {$x$ plane};                                

    \node[color=blue,
        cm={cos(\viewa),-sin(\viewa)*sin(\viewb),
        sin(\viewa),cos(\viewa)*sin(\viewb),
        (0,0)}
            ]   
     at (axis cs:0.5,0.5,0) {$z$ plane};     

    \node[color=black,
        cm={cos(\viewa),-sin(\viewa)*sin(\viewb),
        0,cos(\viewb),
        (0,0)}
            ]   
     at (axis cs:0.5,1,0.5) {$y$ plane};     

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In general, to make a node appear as though it is suspended on a plane with direction vectors u = (u_x,u_y,u_z) and v = (v_z,v_y,v_z)

- Define a = u_x * cos(a) + u_y * sin(a), where a and b are the view angles defined in the LaTeX code above
- Define b = - u_x * sin(a)sin(b) + u_y * cos(a)sin(b) + u_z * cos(b)
- Define c = v_x * cos(a) + v_y * sin(a)
- Define d = - v_x * sin(a)sin(b) + v_y * cos(a)sin(b) + v_z * cos(b)
- Place the node with option `cm={a,b,c,d,(0,0)}`, where a-d represent the expressions above.

In the MWE, I used

- blue text: u = (1,0,0), v = (0,1,0)
- red text: u = (0,1,0), v = (0,0,1)
- black text: u = (1,0,0), v = (0,0,1)