# Rotated numbers on planes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I just got to know tikz used to draw images. I check the manual because I want to draw a image like [image: I download from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vImage/ConvolutionOperations/ConvolutionOperations.html]

I am not sure whether tikz can do this since I found that the number in the grids somehow  has be rotated also. That is , the number seems rotated which is consistent to the planes.

I know draw some lines but I am not sure how to write the text like this.

Any suggestion would be appreciate.

Comment: Maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254010/placing-text-on-face-of-3d-cube or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302539/putting-labels-on-a-cube-with-perspective is helpfull

Comment: Also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212699/text-projection-onto-plane-in-3d-pgf-plots/212811?s=1|0.8804#212811 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141274/sloped-text-along-slanted-paths-in-tikz/141525?s=5|0.5701#141525

Comment: Also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170244/how-to-compute-xslant-and-yslant/170255?s=1|4.9050#170255

Comment: TikZ really isn't the best choice - or the easiest - for 3D. Unless you are just super comfortable with TikZ and not at all with the alternatives, it would be worth your while considering one of the latter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a beginning of solution, I filled the table with any values.

you must use the commands `canvas` to draw on inclined plane and use `transform shape` for as bow node

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows,3d,matrix}

 % see the explanation below
 \makeatletter
 \tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
   \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
   \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
   \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
   \tikz@canvas@is@plane
 }
 \makeatother 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 [x={(0.866cm,0.5cm)}, y={(-0.866cm,0.5cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)}, scale=0.8]




    \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0,transform shape]
      %\draw[blue] (0,0) -- (10,0)--(10,10)--(0,10)--cycle;
      \foreach \ii [count = \xi] in {1,2,3,...,8}{
            \foreach \jj  [count = \yi]in {1,2,3,...,8}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\nn}{int(\xi+8*\yi-8)}
      \node[red,draw,minimum size=1cm] (n\nn-1) at (\ii,-\jj) {\nn};
      }
      }

      \end{scope}

        \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=-7.3,transform shape]
      \foreach \ii [count = \xi] in {1,2,3}{
            \foreach \jj  [count = \yi]in {1,2,3}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\nn}{int(\xi+3*\yi-3)}
      \node[blue,draw,minimum size=1cm] (n\nn-2) at (\ii,-\jj) {\nn};
      }
      }
      \end{scope} 

      \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=-11.2,transform shape]
      \foreach \ii [count = \xi] in {1,2,3,...,8}{
            \foreach \jj  [count = \yi]in {1,2,3,...,8}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\nn}{int(\xi+8*\yi-8)}
      \node[green,draw,minimum size=1cm] (n\nn-3) at (\ii,-\jj) {\nn};
      }
      }
      \end{scope} 

      \draw[fill=red!50,opacity=0.3] (n10-1.north east) -- (n5-2.north east) --(n10-3.north east)
      --(n10-3.north west)-- (n5-2.north west) --  (n10-1.north west)  ;
      \draw[fill=red!50,opacity=0.3] (n10-1.south east) -- (n5-2.south east) --(n10-3.south east)
      --(n10-3.south west)-- (n5-2.south west)-- (n10-1.south west)  ;    
      \draw[fill=red!50,opacity=0.3] (n10-1.north east) -- (n5-2.north east) --(n10-3.north east)
      --(n10-3.south east)-- (n5-2.south east)-- (n10-1.south east)  ;

      \draw[fill=red!50,opacity=0.3] (n10-3.north west)-- (n5-2.north west) --  (n10-1.north west) -- (n10-1.south west)-- (n5-2.south west)   --(n10-3.south west) ;        

  \end{tikzpicture}

  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't `tikz-3dplot` make this easier?