# Create tikz image of restricted map of a plane using

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-3dplot

Can anyone help me to produce the following in Latex (or beamer)?. It is a linear isomorphism $g$ in $R^{3}$ restricted to a plane generated by $v_{1},v_{2}$, and its image is a plane generated by $v_{2},v_{3}.$  I got stuck how to draw these planes since they look as 3D as the following. There is an arrow at the top of the restriction symbol please disregard it. [image]

Comment: Maybe this will help you on your way: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170244/how-to-compute-xslant-and-yslant

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: How they have drawn on the blackboard is how you can draw with TikZ.

Comment: The problem is I could draw it using Geogebra in 2D and I could produce its code to tikz but the planes don't look a 3D planes (also I don't need the (x,y,z) axis to appear). I'm sorry if I attached the picture, but I've tried many times with no results, really sorry. Thanks for your comments.