# Mapping between \xslant, \yslant in scope and degrees?

Tags: tikz-pgf, scoping

In order to project images or text in 2D, an elevation and rotation can be defined and the following scheme can be implemented

```
\def\thexslant{-1}
\def\theyslant{0.5}

\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={%
yslant=\theyslant,%
xslant=\thexslant},%
yslant=\theyslant,%
xslant=\thexslant%
]%
%<content>
\end{scope}%
```

What is the most efficient way to force this with two angles in degrees, say 45, 45?  Please see the following mwe:

```
\documentclass[border=0cm]{standalone}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}%

% orientation
\def\thexslant{-1}
\def\theyslant{0.5}
% this may be equivalent to (-45, 22.5) degrees
% 0.6667 may be equivalent with 30 degrees
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9,every node/.style={minimum size=1cm},on grid]
\begin{scope}[%
yshift=0cm,every node/.append style={%
yslant=\theyslant,xslant=\thexslant},yslant=\theyslant, xslant=\thexslant%
]%
\node[draw=none,anchor=south west,xshift=0cm] (labelf) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{example-image}};%
\end{scope}%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

** I may have redundancy in the `scope` options.

[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170244/how-to-compute-xslant-and-yslant) may be relevant.

Comment: Please, give a fully compilable code.

Comment: tand(-45) = -1, maybe that's it