# Drawing Intelligent Reflecting Surfaces in LaTex

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, circuitikz

How to generate in LaTeX (TikZ or something similar) the following image:

1-IRS (a planner surface that is gridded)

[image: IRS (a planner surface that is gridded)]

I wrote This code but I don't know how to tilt it;

```
\begin{center}
%\fbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[
        box1/.style={draw=black, thick, rectangle,rounded corners, minimum height=0.75cm, minimum width=0.75cm}]
\draw[black,dashed,fill=red!30] (-.5,-3.2) rectangle (3.2,.5);
\node[box1, fill=green!30] (c1) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, right=.125cm of c1] (c2) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, right=.125cm of c2] (c3) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, right=.125cm of c3] (c4) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, below=.125cm of c4] (c5) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, left=.125cm of c5] (c6) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, left=.125cm of c6] (c7) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, left=.125cm of c7] (c8) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, below=.125cm of c8] (c9) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, right=.125cm of c9] (c10) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, right=.125cm of c10] (c11) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, right=.125cm of c11] (c12) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, below=.125cm of c12] (c13) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, left=.125cm of c13] (c14) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, left=.125cm of c14] (c15) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, left=.125cm of c15] (c15) {};
        \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
%}
\end{center}
```

[image]

2-micro controller (a simple circuit-like icon

[image: micro controller (a simple circuit-like icon )]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: Mer30, I use \draw and rotate option

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170244/how-to-compute-xslant-and-yslant

Comment: @StefanPinnow Ok, Thanks

Comment: The simple circuit-like icon is best obtained by loading the graphic you posted here directly, with `\includegraphics`. This question has nothing to do with `circuitikz`, which is used to draw schematics. Moreover, you should ask a question at a time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first problem (you can also use a `foreach` loop to simplify it, but...) you can use `yslant` and `tranform shape` (to apply the slant to also nodes in the picture).

For the second part, the best option is to just use an `\includegraphics` maybe in a node... or in a `circuitikz`'s `twoport` (to give meaning to the tag, really, you can do it easily in pure Ti*k*Z).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[
        box1/.style={draw=black, thick, rectangle,rounded corners, minimum height=0.75cm, minimum width=0.75cm},
        yslant=-0.3, transform shape]
        \draw[black,dashed,fill=red!30] (-.5,-3.2) rectangle (3.2,.5);
        \node[box1, fill=green!30] (c1) {};
        \node[box1, fill=green!30, right=.125cm of c1] (c2) {};
        \node[box1, fill=green!30, right=.125cm of c2] (c3) {};
        \node[box1, fill=green!30, right=.125cm of c3] (c4) {};
        \node[box1, fill=green!30, below=.125cm of c4] (c5) {};
        \node[box1, fill=green!30, left=.125cm of c5] (c6) {};
        \node[box1, fill=green!30, left=.125cm of c6] (c7) {};
        \node[box1, fill=green!30, left=.125cm of c7] (c8) {};
        \node[box1, fill=green!30, below=.125cm of c8] (c9) {};
        \node[box1, fill=green!30, right=.125cm of c9] (c10) {};
        \node[box1, fill=green!30, right=.125cm of c10] (c11) {};
        \node[box1, fill=green!30, right=.125cm of c11] (c12) {};
        \node[box1, fill=green!30, below=.125cm of c12] (c13) {};
        \node[box1, fill=green!30, left=.125cm of c13] (c14) {};
        \node[box1, fill=green!30, left=.125cm of c14] (c15) {};
        \node[box1, fill=green!30, left=.125cm of c15] (c15) {};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \draw (0,0) to[twoport, t={\includegraphics[width=1.8cm]{example-image-duck}}, >, blocks/scale=2] ++(3,0) node[inputarrow]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output from the above snippet]

Comment: Thanks a lot and wish you the best :)