# Inclining text in a plot

Tags: inkscape, psfrag

Using PSFRAG+INKSCAPE and this code:

```latex
% !TeX document-id = {e6a8e82d-b7ef-4afd-9d07-b0a5e7dd8c48}
% !TeX program = txs:///dvi-ps-pdf-chain

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag}

\begin{filecontents*}{dibujo.eps}
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%Creator: 0.46
%%Pages: 1
%%Orientation: Portrait
%%BoundingBox: 117 692 247 746
%%HiResBoundingBox: 117.23092 692.06902 246.90458 745.67044
%%EndComments
%%Page: 1 1
0 842 translate
0.8 -0.8 scale
0 0 0 setrgbcolor
[] 0 setdash
1 setlinewidth
0 setlinejoin
0 setlinecap
gsave [3.543307 0 0 3.543307 4.9321338e-06 0] concat
gsave [0.9147194 0.4040896 0 1 0 0] concat
0 0 0 setrgbcolor
[] 0 setdash
0.3256157 setlinewidth
0 setlinejoin
0 setlinecap
newpath
45.382412 15.761183 moveto
70.217659 15.761183 lineto
70.217659 24.323487 lineto
45.382412 24.323487 lineto
45.382412 15.761183 lineto
closepath
stroke
grestore
gsave [1 0.4417635 0 1 0 0] concat
gsave [1 0 0 -1 43.664242 20.91346] concat
gsave
/newlatin1font {findfont dup length dict copy dup /Encoding ISOLatin1Encoding put definefont} def
/Sans-ISOLatin1 /Sans newlatin1font
4.2333298 scalefont
setfont
0 0 0 setrgbcolor
newpath
0 0 moveto
(text1) show
grestore
grestore
grestore
gsave [-1 0.44176347 0 1 128.45891 -23.356394] concat
0 0 0 setrgbcolor
[] 0 setdash
0.31142199 setlinewidth
0 setlinejoin
0 setlinecap
newpath
41.512173 39.117577 moveto
64.229454 39.117577 lineto
64.229454 47.679881 lineto
41.512173 47.679881 lineto
41.512173 39.117577 lineto
closepath
stroke
grestore
gsave [1 -0.4469484 0 1 0 0] concat
gsave [1 0 0 -1 64.94355 77.981041] concat
gsave
/Sans-ISOLatin1 findfont
4.2333298 scalefont
setfont
0 0 0 setrgbcolor
newpath
0 0 moveto
(text2) show
grestore
grestore
grestore
grestore
showpage
%%EOF
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \psfrag{text1}{$\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x) + g(x) \mathrm{d}x$}
    \psfrag{text2}{Some skewed text}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{dibujo}
    \caption{Notice the skewed text}\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I am able to generate the following drawing:

[image]

In particular notice the nicely skewed text.

However, I know PSFRAG is kind of deprecated, and I would like to switch from the LATEX -> DVI -> PS -> PDF route to PDFLATEX or XELATEX. Therefore, I would like to find an alternative using a recent version of INKSCAPE.

I have tried:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \def\svgwidth{0.5\columnwidth}
    \input{drawing.pdf_tex}
    \caption{Notice the skewed text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

but the result is not what I want:

[image]

TikZ is not an option. I am already very proficient with INKSCAPE.

Comment: If you were using Tikz, you could use xslant or yslant (depending on the oreintation) to effect 3D letters.   I have no idea whether inkscape implements these effects.   See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170244/how-to-compute-xslant-and-yslant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only feasible way I was able to find was to use `pstool`:

```latex
% !TeX program = txs:///pdf-chain/[--shell-escape]

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[crop=pdfcrop]{pstool}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \psfragfig[width=0.5\columnwidth]{dibujo}{%
        \psfrag{text1}{$\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x) + g(x) \mathrm{d}x$}
        \psfrag{text2}{Some skewed text}
    }
    \caption{Notice the skewed text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using INKSCAPE 1.1

(1)  Load the equation with `Extension > Render > Mathematics > LaTex {pdflatex)...`

[image: b]

(2) Save as type  `Latex with PsTricks  macros (*.tex)`

[image: a]

Compile with xelatex or lualatex.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{pstricks} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
            \input{drawing1}
        \caption{Notice the skewed text}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

(I'm being a newbie using INKSCAPE so I'm guessing you how to skew the text boxes and draw the paths.)