# PDF file containing 3D object is not included correctly with \includegraphics

Tags: graphics, pdf, 3d

I have a [PDF file, containing a 3D object](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/52398724/LC.pdf) in PRC format. I try to include this into a LaTeX document to be compiled with `pdflatex`, with the simple source below:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{LC.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Running `pdflatex` (version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12, TeX Live 2011) over this does not yield any error or warning, but the PDF file created does not include the 3D content (in fact, it is empty). The log file for my compilation appears happy, however:

```
<LC.pdf, id=1, 200.74097pt x 196.72597pt>
File: LC.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
 <use LC.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: LC.pdf used on input line 4.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 200.74046pt x 196.72548pt.
 [1 <./LC.pdf>] (./a.aux) )
```

So: what am I doing wrong? How can I include this PDF figure, keeping its 3D content, into a LaTeX document?

Comment: I guess the 3D object is implemented using PDF annotations. These are dropped by `pdftex` because AFAIK they only work reliable in the main PDF, not in an included PDF. The same is true for hyperlinks in included PDFs. I think there might be a way to have them, but `pdftex` doesn't know how to handle included PDF annotations in general. See [How to preserve hyperlinks in included pdf?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14620) which might work as duplicate.

Comment: @Martin Well, I'm sure it can be done, because Acrobat and at least one other PDF editor manage to do it (and I have not yet experienced an issue with this)! But it might be that `pdftex` implementation is lacking in this respect. It is be a bit sad if, after generating my PDF with pdflatex, I have to include my 3D graphs using Acrobat Pro…

Comment: It looks to me like that. You could ask the question on [`comp.text.tex`](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/comp.text.tex) as well, there it will be noticed by the `pdftex` gurus/developers, which might give you an authorized answer on this topic.

Comment: @Martin thanks, I have now [asked on `c.t.t`](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.text.tex/qxWXTgCUQiE)…

Comment: What PDF viewer are you using? I don't think that every PDF viewer is capable of displaying 3D objects like Adobe Reader or Acrobat.

Comment: @egreg I know; I am using Acrobat X Pro (and I also checked with Adobe Reader 9)

Comment: @MartinScharrer: That seems to be what's happening; at least the 3d stuff is made out of annotations, which don't survive the inclusion.

Comment: @MartinScharrer, someone in that conversation suggested that `lualatex` should be able to keep the annotations in the included PDF http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33915/1871. (I never succeeded myself to make it work.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As Martin said, interactive parts of a PDF, called Annotations in PDF specification parlance, such as links or 3D objects, get lost when embedding a PDF containing them. Instead, Annotations have to be re-generated for the new PDF.

To embed a 3D object in the PRC format into a PDF, use LaTeX package `media9`. See `media9` manual, section "[3D quick-start guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/media9.pdf#nameddest=subsection.7.2)".

In case the standalone PRC file is not available it can be extracted from the PDF. This can be done manually, as explained below, or automatically with the help of a small Perl script. Either method requires a tool for uncompressing PDFs, such as [PDFtk](https://gitlab.com/pdftk-java/pdftk).

> *Extracting the PRC from PDF is not recommended if the PRC was generated by `asymptote` and you have the `asy` source file of it!
> Standalone PRC files are generated from `asy` source by*
>
> ```
>     asy --keep --tex pdflatex mysource.asy
> ```

### Automatically, using PDFtk + Perl script

This extracts all PRC streams from `PDFwithPRC.pdf` to separate files `prc-0.prc`, `prc-1.prc`, ...

```
pdftk PDFwithPRC.pdf output - uncompress | perl prcextract.pl
```

On Windows, with a Java runtime and some `perl.exe` installed:

```
java -jar pdftk-all.jar PDFwithPRC.pdf output - uncompress | perl prcextract.pl
```

Perl script `prcextract.pl`:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

$prc=0;
$stream=0;
$cnt=0;

while(<>){
  if(/^stream/) {$stream=1;}
  elsif(/^endstream/) {$stream=0; if($prc){close $PRC;} $prc=0;}
  elsif((/^PRC/ || $prc) && $stream) {
    if(!$prc){open $PRC,">prc-".$cnt++.".prc";select $PRC} print; $prc=1;
  }
}
```

### Manual procedure, by PDFtk + text editor

First uncompress the PDF:

```
pdftk doc.pdf output doc.unc.pdf uncompress
```

Open `doc.unc.pdf` in a text editor and scroll down to a line that starts with `PRC`. This line appears just after a line with the PDF keyword `stream`.

Delete everything from begin of the file up to and including the line containing the `stream` keyword.

Delete everything beginning with the line starting with the `endstream` keyword directly after the PRC stream upto the end of the file.

Save what has left as a file whose name ends in `.prc`.

Comment: `media9` allows include of PRC files into PDF, but not PRC-containing PDF files into PDF. Do you have a solution to extract a PRC from a PDF?

Comment: It's possible. See my edit.

Comment: Your example file was generated using `asymptote`. In that case it is much better to create a standalone PRC from the `asy` source file and include it with `media9`. See my [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51185/how-to-get-rid-of-the-viewers-incorrect-axes-in-an-asymptote-3d-graphics/51776#51776) to your previous question.

Comment: extracting the PRC stream like that and including it later with `media9` looses all the valuable information: size & aspect ratio, viewpoint, external javascript, etc. I'm afraid it just doesn't work: there is more to the 3D PDF graphics than just the PRC stream…

Comment: @Regarding Asymptote, yes, I understand it's easier with the PRC file… but then again, you need not only the `.prc` but a lot of auxiliary files, which is a pain (compared to the simple PDF). In the end, the answer seems to be that `pdftex` simply doesn't support this kind of inclusion, and no one is interested enough to fix it (I am interested, but not to the point of hacking `pdftex` without any prior experience!).

Comment: Under the hood, Asympote uses my old `movie15.sty` package for including the PRC into PDF. It is obsolete and to be replaced by the new `media9`. There is not much about the additional JavaScript file you are referring to and which Asymtote attaches. It only enables billboard behaviour of textlabels (labels always facing the camera) and setting orthographic view instead of perspective view. All this can be done easily with `media9` (add3Djscript=asylabels.js, 3Dortho). The optimal viewpoint, size&aspect ration can be set from within Reader, just right-click on `Generate Default View`.

Comment: @F'x: If you want to add support for this to some engine, please add it to LuaTeX - it's probably already possible in Lua (and if not, the missing pieces can be added).

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to do the same with a U3D file embedded in a PDF?

Comment: I tried this approach but cannot get it to work. I used the really basic example:

    \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{media9}
    \begin{document}
    \includemedia[width=10 cm,activate=pageopen, 3Dmenu]{}{boxunc.prc}
    \end{document}

The latest release of Acrobat Reader gives the error that the 3Dformat is supported by a more recent release. (Which is not possible). The original prc comes from a pdf that can be opened and works. (How do I upload a prc file here?)

Comment: @MichelJanssens You need to specify `height` as well, since the last-but-one argument (poster text) is empty. Given the last argument is a valid PRC file, continue to follow the 3D tutorial in the media9 documentation.

Comment: Thanks Alex, The result is the same when I specify the height. I think the problem is the prc-file. The solution describes how to extract a prc-file from an existing pdf. I have an existing pdf with a working 3D in it. I follow the procedure described above and that does not work. (I must admit I have no idea what information is stored where in the prc, it is binary.)

Comment: If I leave the lines stream and endstream around the binary stuff, it does not give the error but acrobat reader crashes (after a while) when I do "generate default view" as is described in the media9 documentation.

Comment: Delete stream and endstream. You only need the binary stuff in between.

Comment: Then I get the error I mentioned.

Comment: @MichelJanssens Could you please make the PDF containing the PRC file available for download (dropbox, perhaps)?

Comment: Dear AlexG,Sorry it took so long. Here is a small file with just a box. Thanks in advance for looking at it. https://www.dropbox.com/t/vriFB1RT8c7hm2HH

Comment: @MichelJanssens : This is the PRC I extracted from your example: [`box.prc`](http://agrahn.gitlab.io/tex/box.prc) , and this the embedding example I get by strictly following the
3D quick-start guide  (section 7.2 of the `media9` manual): [`boxWithMedia9.tex`](https://agrahn.gitlab.io/tex/boxWithMedia9.tex), [`boxWithMedia9.pdf`](https://agrahn.gitlab.io/tex/boxWithMedia9.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, your PRC file works here too. I guess I am doing something wrong with the extraction of the prc-file from the pdf. You already have the normal pdf. Here is the uncompressed pdf I use: https://www.dropbox.com/t/DVFDdRhCeCkaNIr2

Comment: and this is the prc file I get out of that: https://www.dropbox.com/t/WrnRHVigRCvXkWf6 I am obviously doing something wrong.

Comment: @MichelJanssens I get the same error if I use the standard Windows Notepad text editor for extracting the PRC. Usually, I work with Vim on Linux. Could you try some advanced editor, say, Notepad++ ?

Comment: It works now (Notepad++ for extraction). Thanks a lot. You really helped me out.

Comment: I even **don't** get it correctly with Notepad++. Did modify the encoding when saving as PRC?

Comment: Yes, I think it has to do with the encoding. Default Notepad++ is in ANSI (for ASCII). Therefore, it does not work if you copy the binary stream. It works only if you delete the ASCII stuff and then save as...

Comment: @MichelJanssens I added a script based method, in case you are interested.

Comment: Thanks, I already scripted it so it is one operation now. (This also eliminates the encoding problem.) Regards, Michel