# Include a PDF containing an animation (movie15)

Tags: pdf, pdfpages, animations, movie15

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [PDF file containing 3D object is not included correctly with \includegraphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52018/pdf-file-containing-3d-object-is-not-included-correctly-with-includegraphics)
>   [How to preserve hyperlinks in included pdf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14620/2975)

I am using LaTeX, and at some point need to insert a PDF file. Ok, got that one working with `\includepdf`. However the inserted PDF contains an animation (slides 26-29, you need to click on the image). The file is properly inserted, however the animation does not work.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{pdfpages,epstopdf,hyperref,movie15}
\begin{document}
qwe
\includepdf[pages={-},landscape]{Rate-Effects-Presentation.pdf}
\end{document}
```

The file to be inserted is http://civil.colorado.edu/~saouma/Rate-Effects-Presentation.pdf 
and the output of the log file is in http://civil.colorado.edu/~saouma/junk2.log.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post. A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: That's a duplicate of the recent question [PDF file containing 3D object is not included correctly with includegraphics](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52018/2975) or [How to preserve hyperlinks in included pdf?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14620/2975) Short answer: These things (animations, hyperlinks, etc.) are implemented as PDF annotations which are dropped by `pdftex` when included a PDF, because it is not able to reintegrate them into the main PDF. (Adobe Acrobat seems to be able to do this.)