# How can i import a 3D SolidWorks Model into my PDF using LaTeX

Tags: pdf, 3d, pst-solides3d

Acrobat Adobe supports 3D PDFs to be included into LaTeX.

I could use another tool to create a PDF and import that PDF into my build, but i would rather use a package o include a solid works model directly via my latex compiler.

The result schould look like [one](http://www.adobe.com/manufacturing/3dpdfsamples/pdfs/turbine_engine_re.pdf) of the results on the [Adobe Demo page](http://www.adobe.com/manufacturing/3dpdfsamples/3dsolutions/). Including the users ability to freely rotate the Unit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If SolidWorks can export the model to either u3d or prc (preferred) file formats, you can embed that into your document using the [media9](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/media9.pdf#page=27) package.

If, however, only PDF with the embedded interactive model can be exported, you may extract the u3d or prc data into a standalone file using `pdftk` and a text editor. Instructions are given in another [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52090/1053).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of extracting 3D model from the Solidworks PDF file, you can embed Solidworks PDF file as a whole into LaTeX PDF file.

The PDF format allows the inclusion of files inside the PDF document. The included files can be bound to an annotation on a page. Or they can be recorded in a sorted list of embedded files. The packages `attachfile` or `attachfile2` follow the first approach, package `embedfile` uses the latter method.