# Include a functional 3D pdf file

Tags: pdf, include

I have a 3D pdf file (.pdf) I want to include in an appendix (image 5). When opening the file separately with Adobe Reader, one can zoom in on the object, rotate it etc. I would like to have the same possibilities in the Appendix of my final pdf-file, if possible.

I have made the model with the software "Agisoft PhotoScan". In my code below, I have included a similar free download model, "sample01.pdf" from their pages (http://www.agisoft.com/forum/index.php?topic=191.0). No intention of advertisement, just declaring as much information as possible.

When I try to include the file as a pdf, the page does not show the model correctly: its blank, with only the softwares signature below (p. 3). I have tried several options, but the best I have managed so far is the "\attachfile{} solution" in appendix B.

I addition, the pdf file skip one page as shown (p. 2-3). This is my 2.priority concern, but would also be nice to fix. Can anybody help? Is it at all possible, or do I have to somehow merge the separate 3D pdf file with my latex compiled pdf? Help would be outmost appreciated :)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{attachfile}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]

\appendix
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage %Remove blank page betwenen chap1 and Appx.A
\chapter{3D pdf file}
\includepdf{sample01.pdf}

\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage %Remove blank page between Appx.A and Appx.B
\chapter{Enclosed 3D pdf file}
I manage to attach the file with a pin which opens the file seperately in Adobe Reader: \attachfile{sample01.pdf} \\
However, I would rather integrate the file in Appendix A if possible.

\end{document}
```

[image] 
[image]
[image]
[image]

The pdf file I try to include with my sample code:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need the original PRC or U3D file embedded in `sample01.pdf` and embed it into your document using the `media9` package. Extracting the 3D PRC file is explained here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52090 . In case of U3D, just replace PRC with U3D in the instruction steps.