# No 3D graphic in output PDF file using media9

Tags: media9

I want to attach a 3D file from Inventor to my pdf, I have done what was said in this comment https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52090/1053, but after compiling pdf, I can see only origin of the 3D file, but the part appear after I click to full screen multimedia option:

[image: no1]

[image: no2]

[image: no3]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{lmodern}                    % czcionka Palatino
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                % wymagane do dzialania czcionki Palatino
\linespread{1.05}                       % interlinia, 1.05 ze wzgledu na czcionke Palatino

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             % kodowanie dokumentu
\usepackage[english,polish]{babel}      % kroj czcionki w jezyku polskim i angielskim
\usepackage[MeX]{polski}                % slownik lamania wyrazow w jezyku polskim

\usepackage{graphicx}                   % pakiet graficzny, wymagany do wstawiania rysunkow
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includemedia[
    width=13cm,
    height=13cm,
    activate=pageopen,
    ]{}{pinlock.prc}
    \caption{XXX}
\label{Fig:pinlock}
\end{figure}\par

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Got it!

Including "3Dmenu" option in includemedia will give us "Generate Default View" option under right mouse clicking in acrobat which has the details of camera position to put them in includemedia, in my case:

```
3Dcoo=182 0 168,
3Droo=452.165702187109,
3Dlights=Headlamp,
```

It is all described in the package documentation heh... Thanks to the Author!